# Using a common property in serilog Logs

Tags: c#, .net, serilog

I am currently trying to understand serilogs for structured Logging.
Is there a way to enforce common Property to be used in serilog . Like if I have a log written in code like below

```
log.Info("Disk Quota {​​​​​​​DiskQuota}​​​​​​​ exceeded by user {​​​​​​​Username}​​​​​​​", 100, "User1")
```

How can I use message template to ensure that any future log written in 2 to 3 classes where disk quota exceeding warning could be thrown and needs to be logged, uses always {Username} only and not {user} or {userid} etc.

```
log.Info("Disk Quota {​​​​​​​DiskQuota}​​​​​​​ exceeded by user {​​​​​​​User}​​​​​​​", 100, "User2") // Disallow , Possibly ??
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing out-of-the-box in Serilog that does that for you.

A good solution to this would be to implement your own [source code analyzer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019), that can perform these checks during the build and emit warnings and/or errors when messages are similar but have different property names.

You'd have to define a [String metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) to decide what "similar" means to you. There are a number of [String metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_metric) you can use, and each of them are similar but have some different characteristics, with the popular ones being:

- [Levenshtein Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance): The minimum number of single-character edits required to change one word into the other. Strings do not have to be the same length;
- [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance): The number of characters that are different in two equal length strings;
- [Smith–Waterman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith-Waterman_algorithm): A family of algorithms for computing variable sub-sequence similarities;
- [Sørensen–Dice Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dice%27s_coefficient): A similarity algorithm that computes difference coefficients of adjacent character pairs.

You also leverage parts of the source code of the [SerilogAnalyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) project to find message templates in code, and perform the checks.

---

A much more simple solution (but not as effective because relies on good developer behavior) would be to declare these standard message templates in a class, inside of a project that is shared across your solution, so that you can reference them instead everywhere instead of typing.

e.g.

```
public static class LogMessageTemplates
{
    public const string DiskQuotaExceededByUsername = "Disk Quota {​​​​​​​DiskQuota}​​​​​​​ exceeded by user {​​​​​​​Username}​​​​​​​";
}
```

And then everywhere you'd rely on developers to always use these pre-defined message templates, instead of typing the strings directly. e.g.:

```
log.Info(LogMessageTemplates.DiskQuotaExceededByUsername, 100, "User1");
```

If you use this approach you'll probably want to install [SerilogAnalyzer](https://github.com/Suchiman/SerilogAnalyzer) in the project to help you identify places where the message template has `X` parameters but you are using `Y` given that it's now more difficult to spot how many properties a message template has just by looking at the name.

Comment: Thank you so much for a detailed response. Right now I guess, i would go with the declaring standard messages templates and will explore SerilogAnalyzers. Thanks again.